# sklearn in Python 3.4 "ImportError: cannot import name 'datasets'"

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining

I am using python 3.4 for clustering,and write this code:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
```

even I have installed related modules but there is below error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'datasets'
```

what is problem?

Comment: I think its helpful to add more details. Can you write the line before `ImportError`?. Its important to identify if the error is first coming from the `installed module` or from the `python script` your are writing.

Comment: Do you have `scipy` installed? What happens if you try to do a direct `import sklearn.datasets`?

Comment: Maybe try `pip install --upgrade sklearn` and run again?

Comment: always add in question full error message (Traceback) because there are more useful inforamation - ie. what file makes problem. of if you used name `sklearn.py` for your file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use the [cluster tutorial on sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_iris.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-cluster-iris-py)?

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import datasets
```

Comment: I have installed scipy as well,here is the full error message:

Comment: @iman I think the problem you have is probably you have a couple of different versions of python and you are installing it into the wrong version.

If I were you I would install [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) and then use Anaconda Prompt and run python from there. (or better start using the jupyter notebooks).

Anaconda comes preinstalled the numpy, sklearn and many other packages with their dependencies.